# Algorithm for achieving best finish time for a team in a triathlon race

Tags: java, algorithm

Teacher plans a race, each contestant must complete 20laps of swimming, followed by 10kms cycling followed by 3kms running. For example In other words, first one contestant swims the 20 laps, gets out, and starts biking. As soon as this first person is out of the pool, a second contestant begins swimming the20 laps; as soon as he or she is out and starts biking, a third contestant begins swimming . . . and so on

Each contestant has a projected swimming time means expected time to complete 20 laps of swimming, also each contestant has projected cycling and running time. The question is design a schedule for race i.e and order in which to sequence the starts of contestant. The participant can bike and race simultaneously but at most only person can be in the pool.

**Question: design an efficient algorithm to schedule the above task ?
    Also a program to prove the algorithm is right.**

**Attempted solution:**
I have come up with this idea : 
Initialize the contestants from 1 to n,
Let si, bi, ri denote the swimming, cycling and running time contestant i .
We arrange the contestant in decreasing order of the time taken to cycle+time taken to run and send them in this order.
Iam not able to formulate the the algorithm and program  properly, so need help with that.

Comment: If you want to order them by the amount of time that it takes them, look into to using a PriorityQueue which will allow you to get the next person with the fastest time.

Comment: What help do you need? Can you post the pseudo code or actual java code for what you have tried so far and where are you getting stuck? Otherwise it just looks like you are asking for people to complete this assignment for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to worry about two simple rules :

1. If we send the contestant that takes the least amount of time to swim first, we are reducing the finish time between contestants.
2. What if two contestants have the same swim time? In this case, the contestants who have a higher total running + cycling time should be sent first so that they can get a head start for the remaining activities.

Consider the time each contestant takes for a particular activity:

```
Contestant->Swim time(mins)->Run time(mins)->Cycle time(mins)
A->1->1->1
B->2->1->1
C->1->1->1
```

**Case 1 :**
Contestant with maximum swim time goes first. Race starts at 12:00 PM in the order B, A, C, we have :

```
Swimming complete->Running complete->Cycling complete
B->12:02->12:03->12:04
A->12:03->12:04->12:05
C->12:04->12:05->12:06
```

**Case 2 :**
Contestant with maximum swim time goes second. Race starts at 12:00 PM in the order A, B, C, we have :

```
Swimming complete->Running complete->Cycling complete
A->12:01->12:02->12:03
B->12:03->12:04->12:05
C->12:04->12:05->12:06
```

**Case 3 :**
Contestant with maximum swim time goes third. Race starts at 12:00 PM in the order A, C, B we have :

```
Swimming complete->Running complete->Cycling complete
A->12:01->12:02->12:03
C->12:02->12:03->12:04
B->12:04->12:05->12:06
```

You can see that in all the cases, the last contestant finishes the race at 12:06. However, in Case 1 (Contestant with maximum swim time goes first), the first contestant finishes at 12:04 PM and second contestant finishes at 12:05. In case two (Contestant with maximum swim time goes second), the first contestant finishes the race at 12:03 and the second contestant at 12:05. In case 3 (Contestant with maximum swim time goes third), the first contestant finishes the race at 12:03 and the second contestant finishes the race at 12:04. This is by far the most efficient order since by 12:04, you already have two contestants who have finished the race.

But what if two contestants have the same swim time but different cycle and run time. Consider :

```
Contestant->Swim time(mins)->Run time(mins)->Cycle time(mins)
A->1->1->1
B->2->2->1
C->2->1->1
```

**Case 4 :** From the two contestants with the same swimming time, the contestant with a lower total of cycling and running time goes first :

```
Swimming complete->Running complete->Cycling complete
A->12:01->12:02->12:03
C->12:03->12:04->12:05
B->12:05->12:07->12:08
```

**Case 5 :** From the two contestants with the same swimming time, the contestant with a higher total of cycling and running time goes first :

```
Swimming complete->Running complete->Cycling complete
A->12:01->12:02->12:03
B->12:03->12:05->12:06
C->12:05->12:06->12:07
```

As can be seen, the last contestant finishes the race at 12:08 PM in case 4 whereas the last contestant finishes the race at 12:07 in case 5. This implies that if two contestants have the same swim time, the contestant with the higher total of cycling+running time should go first.

To code this in Java :

First create a class to hold contestant information :

```
public class Contestant {
    private String name;
    private Map<String,Integer> timings = new HashMap<>();

    public Contestant(String name, Map<String, Integer> timings) {
        this.name = name;
        this.timings = timings;
    }

    public Integer getTimingFor(String activity) {
        return timings.get(activity);
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getTimings() {
        return timings;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}
```

Then create a Comparator that will decide which contestant should go before another contestant. The idea is to order the contestants in the order of swimming time (ascending) and then in the order of the remaining activities (descending)

```
  public class ContestantComparator implements Comparator<Contestant> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Contestant one, Contestant two) {
        int contestantOneSwimTime = one.getTimingFor("Swimming");
        int contestantTwoSwimTime = two.getTimingFor("Swimming");

        if(contestantOneSwimTime<contestantTwoSwimTime) {
            return -1;
        } else if(contestantOneSwimTime>contestantTwoSwimTime) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int c1RemainingTimeExceptSwimming = 0;
            int c2RemainingTimeExceptSwimming = 0;

            for(String activity : one.getTimings().keySet()) {
                if(!activity.equals("Swimming")) {
                    c1RemainingTimeExceptSwimming+=one.getTimingFor(activity);
                }
            }

            for(String activity : two.getTimings().keySet()) {
                if(!activity.equals("Swimming")) {
                    c2RemainingTimeExceptSwimming+=two.getTimingFor(activity);
                }
            }

            if(c1RemainingTimeExceptSwimming>c2RemainingTimeExceptSwimming) {
                return -1;
            } else if(c1RemainingTimeExceptSwimming<c2RemainingTimeExceptSwimming) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main class to use the code :

```
public class Contest {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Map<String,Integer> timings = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        timings.put("Swimming", 1);
        timings.put("Running", 1);
        timings.put("Cycling", 1);
        Contestant a = new Contestant("A",timings);

        timings = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        timings.put("Swimming", 1);
        timings.put("Running", 2);
        timings.put("Cycling", 1);
        Contestant b = new Contestant("B",timings);

        timings = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        timings.put("Swimming", 1);
        timings.put("Running", 2);
        timings.put("Cycling", 2);
        Contestant c = new Contestant("C",timings);

        List<Contestant> contestants = new ArrayList<Contestant>();
        contestants.add(a);
        contestants.add(b);
        contestants.add(c);
        Collections.sort(contestants,new ContestantComparator());

        for(Contestant contestant : contestants) {
            System.out.println(contestant.getName());
        }

    }

}
```

Note that the Contestant class contains a Map. The purpose of this map is to allow you to add any number of tasks for the contestants without the need to change your code. The key represents the activity such as swimming and the value (Integer) represents the time for the corresponding activity.

Comment: the time complexity of the code is O(n^2).

Comment: I thought it this way - if there are n contestants then we will go till the last n  to select the person with earliest deadline.This loop will run for n times. My bad I guess was wrong in the first go T.C will be O(n)

Comment: oops sorry man i wasn't aware of that actually my laptop got freezed at this site and was clicking haphazardly it must have happened at that time, aslo I am new to the site interface so it will take time for me to get used to,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and efforts, though i have some doubts in your program

Comment: I did not get what this part of the code does?
else {
       int P1TimeExceptSwimming = 0;
                int P2TimeExceptSwimming = 0;
             
       for(String activity : one.getTimings().keySet()) {
        if(!activity.equals("Swimming")) {
         P1TimeExceptSwimming+=one.getTimeFrame(activity);
        }
       }
       
       for(String activity : two.getTimings().keySet()) {
        if(!activity.equals("Swimming")) {
         P2TimeExceptSwimming+=two.getTimeFrame(activity);
        }
       }
       
       if(P1TimeExceptSwimming>P2TimeExceptSwimming) {
        return -1;

Answer (score -1):

This is a clear case of greedy programming(Note : greedy is not the optimal choice always) :
I assume here that you want to minimize the total time as it is not mentioned here.

Algorithm :

1. Let si, bi, ri denote the swimming, cycling and running time contestant i.
2. sort contestants by the time they take to complete all three tasks, sort them in descending order.
3. schedule them according to the order from step 2

For sorting the contestants :

1. Calculate the time required by each to swim,bike and run.
2. add these time, and sort them in descending order.

Comment: It's really not as simple as sorting them in descending order of total time. See my answer.

Comment: Its greedy approach, not sure if its optimal. But what i did here is the contestant who is the slowest should be sent out first and so on, and the contestant who is fastest should be sent out last because he can cover the others. In your approach, if the contestant who has the least swimming time is sent out last but what if his cycling and running time is very very large. You would end up increasing the total time. So considering the total time would be good according to me.

Comment: @bot if there are 2 contestants (10,10,10) and (9,20,30) with your approach
you would send contestant 1 st so when he done swimming after 10 you would send the next contestant.
total time : 10 + 9 + 20 + 30 = 69 units

with my approach I would send in contestant 2 first :
with my approach
total time : 9 + 20 + 30 = 59 units

There is a basic constraint given here : *The participant can bike and race simultaneously but at most only person can be in the pool.*

Comment: I would send {9,20,30} first and {10,10,10} second. Looks like you did not understand my approach.

Comment: @bot ok if the times are.. (9,10,10) & (10,20,30).. with your approach it will it will take 9+ 10 + 20 + 30 = 69 and with my approach it will take 10 + 20 + 30 = 60 and btw i'm not here to prove my approach is right or wrong or prove anything about your approach. I'm here to learn myself and help others and also understand different ways of solving the problem. So you wanted a input eg thats what I gave here.

Comment: Why will the time with your approach be 10+20+30? The first contestant also has to swim!!! Only one person can swim at a time. You have to add the 9 minutes for the first contestant to swim in your approach as well. You can't consider the 9 minutes of the first contestant being covered with the 10 minutes of the second contestant because swimming cannot take place in parallel! No matter what approach you use for your inputs, 10+9 is unavoidable!! Besides, this is the only case where both our approaches will take the same time. Any other case passed to your algorithm will give bad timings.

Comment: Why to add 9? the 1st contestant wont start until 2nd one finishes swimming. after 2nd contestant finishes swimming he still has to do task worth 20 + 30 = 50 time units and by that time 1st one will start and do his 9+10+10 = 29 time unit task even before 2nd contestant finishes his work. so the total time still stays 60. Please note swimming is not in parallel by other things are. With your approach 1st contestant will go and will finish swimming in 9 units, then 2nd contestant starts and takes more 60 units so total of 69

Comment: @PrasadShinde 
The reason why to add 9 is because of the constraint that only one person can be swimming in the pool at a time. Using your approach, you are assuming that both swimmer 1 and 2 can swim at the same time. Your 10 instead of 9 means that "10 > 9 therefore 10 for first swim time" which contradicts the specifications. Another way to see it is everyone has to wait 9 minutes for a swimmer to finish, then 10 minutes for another, and so on.