# Finding the sequence so that the event is finished at the earliest

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a problem from informatica olympiad that I am trying to solve since sometime. This is important for me since this contains an underlying fundamental problem that I see in a lot of problems.

Given N citizens for an event such that they have to program on a single computer, eat chocolates and then eat doughnuts. time , ith citizen takes for each task is given as input. Each citizen has to finish the tasks in order, i.e., first program then eat chocolate and then eat doughnuts. Any number of people could eat chocolates or doughnuts at a time but since computer is one only 1 person can program each time. Once, he is done he would move to chocolates and next person shall program. The task is to find the order in which citizens be sent out to program such that event ends in minimum time and this time is the output.

I worked this problem using the approach:
If I start with ith citizen then for remaining n-1 citizens if I find the time (tn-1) then tn = max((ni[0]+ni[1]+ni[2]), ni[0] + tn-1). Eg.: 
18 7 6
23 10 27
20 9 14

then 18+7+6, 18+23+10+27, 18+23+20+9+14, max would be 84 but if you start with 23 then time would be 74 which is less.

I implemented this approach whose code I am presenting here. However, the complexity is O(n!) for my approach. I can see underlying repeated subproblems,so I could use DP approach. But the problem is I need to store the time value for each list i to j such that it could begin with any k from i to j and so on. This storage process would again be complex and require n! storage. How, to solve this problem and similar such problems?

Here is my program on my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

int min_time_sequence(std::vector<std::vector<int> > Info, int N)
{
    if (N == 0) return 0;
    if (N == 1)
    {
        int val = Info[0][0] + Info[0][1] + Info[0][2];
        return val;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > tmp = Info;
    int mn = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        //prepare new list
        tmp.erase(tmp.begin()+i);
        int mn = min_time_sequence(tmp, N-1);
        int v1 = Info[i][0] + mn;
        int v2 = Info[i][0] + Info[i][1] + Info[i][2];
        int larger = v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2;
        if (mn > larger) mn = larger;
    }
    return mn;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin>>N;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > Info;
    //input
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cin>>Info[i][0];
        std::cin>>Info[i][1];
        std::cin>>Info[i][2];
    }
    int mx = 0;
    if (N > 0)
        mx = min_time_sequence(Info, N);
    std::cout<<mx<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a weighted interval scheduling problem with a bit of extra complexity added to determine if jobs are compatible.  You can do it in O(nlogn) time with some work, and there's lots of resources on the web once you know what to search for.

Comment: This is not a weighted interval scheduling problem, neither can I think of how to approximate it as the same. Here, there is no start or end time, any citizen could start any time, so how to reconcile? can, you provide an approach if you have figured this out?

Comment: Here is the link to a similar problem but I don't see how the approach presented would work?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648370/algorithm-for-achieving-best-finish-time-for-a-team-in-a-triathlon-race

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for general techniques, you might want to look at *greedy algorithms*, that is, algorithms that repeatedly optimize the next selection.  In this case, that might be for the remaining person who will take the longest total time (the sum of the three times) to program next, so he or she will finish eating sooner, and no one who starts later will take more time.

**If** such an algorithm were optimal, the program could simply sort the list by the sum of times, in decreasing order, which takes O(*N* log *N*) time.

You would, however, be expected to prove that your solution is valid.  One way to do that is known as “Greedy Stays Ahead.”  That is an inductive proof where you show that the solution your greedy algorithm produces is at least as optimal (by some measure equivalent to optimality at the final step) at its first step, then that it is also as good at its second step, the step after that, and so on.  Hint: you might try measuring what is the worst-case scenario for how much time the event could need after each person starts programming.  At the final step, when the last person gets to start programming, this is equivalent to optimality.

Another method to prove an algorithm is optimal is “Proof by Exchange.” This is a form of proof by contradiction in which you hypothesize that some different solution is optimal, then you show that exchanging a part of that solution with a part of your solution could improve the supposedly-optimal solution.  That contradicts the premise that it was ever optimal—which proves that no other solution is better than this.  So: assume the optimal order is different, meaning the last person who finishes started after someone else who took less time.  What happens if you switch the positions of those two people?

Greedy solutions are not always best, so in cases where they are not, you would want to look at other techniques, such as symmetry-breaking and pruning the search tree early.

Comment: No, greedy won't work here. Consider the values:
18 7 6
23 10 27
20 9 14

starting with 23 and then 20 would be the solution although 23 is greater than 18 (solution also depends on values for eating chocolates and doughnuts)

Comment: @RohitRoy Maybe take another look at what the algorithm does? It sorts based on the sum of the three times for each person, not programming time alone. In your example, IIUC, there are three people whose total times are 18+7+6=31, 23+10+27=60, and 20+9+14=43. So the greedy algorithm says to start with person 2 (who programs in 23), and then person 3 (who programs in 20), which is correct (you can verify that this takes 66 time, which is optimal).

Comment: Added a clarification to the first paragraph, as I can see how this misreading happened.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I tried this but not getting the right result. Approach I tried is to sort the sums of 3 values for all in the decreasing order (if 2 values of sums are same then the one with lower programming time shall precede). Then I calculated the max time in the sorted ordered sequence but am not getting correct result. Here is my code:
https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/13481927

Comment: Not letting me see it. I might have made an error, but can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of code chef test cases but its definitely failing for some of them. I have uploaded my code on github (public repo):
https://github.com/CodeWithKartik/DesignPatterns

Look for file titled interview_scheduling.cpp

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of code chef test cases but its definitely failing for some of them. I have uploaded my code on github (public repo): github.com/CodeWithKartik/DesignPatterns Look for file titled interview_scheduling.cpp